# Testing doze and standby mode

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I switched off the screen display of my Nexus 5 device running Android M and then issued the following commands.

```
im17-x0:~ r.j$ adb shell dumpsys battery unplug
im17-x0:~ r.j$ adb shell dumpsys deviceidle step
Stepped to: IDLE_PENDING
im17-x0:~ r.a$ adb shell dumpsys deviceidle step
Stepped to: SENSING
im17-x0:~ r.a$ adb shell dumpsys deviceidle step
Stepped to: IDLE
```

Now ideally my device should go to idle mode. But i started a `CountDownTimer` before putting it in idle mode and its still running.
Also the network access is still there in my phone ( checked using [this](http://pastebin.com/nBuh2UVV) function)

Why is the device not going in doze mode? Following the options from [here](https://developer.android.com/preview/testing/guide.html#doze-standby) for standby mode also has the same effect. Why?

Also in that timer,if i check for `isDeviceIdleMode()`, it returns true.

Comment: Did you get the reason for this behaviour? I also have a similar use case and my timer seems to be running  not being affected by Doze mode. But isDeviceIdleMode() returns true in logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, the behavior looks like this

1. `isDeviceIdleMode()` will return true.
2. Network availability check in the app always returns true.( Checked    using [this](http://pastebin.com/nBuh2UVV) function)
3. There is no change in the network (no network broadcast fired ) when    a device enters and comes out of doze mode. However, there is a    broadcast fired(doze broadcast)  when the device goes into and comes    out of doze mode.
4. However we can’t make a network call in doze mode.( Tried using    `HttpUrlConnection`)

For `getNetworkInfo()` returning true in doze mode, there is a bug reported in Android ([Link](https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=3164))

Comment: late reply, but...the 3rd point: What do you mean by there is no change? I now developing on MM, updated my Huawei Mate 7 to MM and realized that as soon as the device goes to doze mode, the Network changes. I have made some logs on my app and there is a change from Wifi to Mobile connection and back. Is this a bug made by Huawei Implementation or is this a normal MM behaviour?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs I hink he means that any existing tcp connection does not die automatically and continues to report as connected but cannot transmit nor receive data

Answer (score 1):

I've got a few tips for you here:

**Network Access**

I'd suggest testing network access by actually attempting a network call and logging it out. There's a documented bug with checking network access programmatically while in idle mode: 
https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=3164

**Checking Idle/Doze Mode**

There isn't much documentation out there, but there are some methods which aren't muted by Doze mode. Using `CountDownTimer` might be one of those. I'd try setting an alarm using [setExact()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExact(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)), which has been documented not to work when the app is in idle mode. If you can log something out when that alarm fires, you're definitely not in idle mode.

Let me know how that works for you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is some useful information on Idle Mode:

**deviceidle** - Is a new android service, that will always run and listen for the several system events, which can trigger it in/out of the idle mode (also known as a Doze mode):

```
1.Screen on/off
2.Charging status
3.Significant motion detect
```

**DeviceIdleController** - When the device is awake and in-use, the controller is in the ACTIVE state. External events like inactivity time-out, user powering off the screen, motion detection ... will drive the state machine into INACTIVE. 
This state machine contains seven states:

```
1.ACTIVE - Device is in use, or connected to a charge source.
2.INACTIVE - Device has recently come out of the active state, meaning that user turned off the display or unplugged it.
3.IDLE_PENDING - Hold on, we are about to enter idle mode.
4.SENSING
5.LOCATING
6.IDLE - Device is idle.
7.IDLE_MAINTENANCE - Window is open for applications to do processing. Then will back to IDLE.
```

**Idle State** - In order to put the device into an Idle state you can use the following adb commands:

```
>adb shell dumpsys battery unplug
>adb shell dumpsys deviceidle force-idle
```

**Active State** - In order to put the device back into the Active state you may simulate the following key event:

```
> adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_WAKEUP
```

I also needed a quick option to toggle between Active and Idle states so I wrote a batch script ***adbIdleModeSwitch.bat*** for these purposes, you may download and use it:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B81qFnPX_eUUYTMxOTd1UG94NVk/view

Comment: I tried the commands `adb shell dumpsys deviceidle force-idle` and `adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_WAKEUP` and thought they had no effect. Turns out the first one does after a minute or two.

Answer (score 0):

I think the network will still come back as connected while in doze ( if you have a network connection) , however if you try to do anything other than GCM it will throw you an error.

Answer (score 0):

**REWRITE:** My original answer hypothesized that your device wasn't actually in Doze mode, hence the link to [improved instructions for getting into Doze mode](https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=2930) and [Diving Into Android 'M' Doze](https://newcircle.com/s/post/1739/2015/06/12/diving-into-android-m-doze) about `IDLE_MAINTENANCE` state where network activities are allowed to run.

My new hypothesis is (1) when `deviceidle step` replies `Stepped to: IDLE`, the device *is* in Doze mode, and (2) Doze mode is not behaving as we expect.

Google has updated the page [**Optimizing for Doze and App Standby**](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html), but it doesn't jive with your findings. They've provided additional info at [Understanding what Doze mode means for your app](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/94jCkmG4jff) and [A flowchart for background work, alarms, and your Android app](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/GdNrQciPwqo). Also see [Issue 2225](https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=2225).

I'm afraid this still doesn't explain your results. Doze mode is complicated and under-documented.

Q. Is your app whitelisted? The **Optimizing for Doze and App Standby** page says:

> An app that is whitelisted can use the network and hold partial wake locks during Doze and App Standby.

BTW, the command

```
adb shell dumpsys deviceidle
```

displays the current state (e.g. `IDLE`) and other info including the charging, motion, and screen on/off state that are prerequisites for Dozing, also the *whitelist*. This is useful for debugging.

Comment: This does not answer my question. You have basically written the same steps that i wrote in my question.

Comment: @Diffy indeed, I have discarded that hypotheses and rewritten the answer with a new one.

Comment: @Diffy is your app whitelisted? That could explain it.

Comment: No my app is not whitelisted @Jerry101.